# JavaScript heap out of memory - identify problem with chrome developer tools

Tags: react-native, memory, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, heap-memory

Im building an app with react native and expo.
This error occured when starting the app, as soon as loading hits 99%:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[8936:09216D50]    39714 ms: Scavenge 319.8 (362.4) -> 319.1 (369.2) MB, 3.1 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.983, current mu = 0.891) allocation failure;
[8936:09216D50]    39881 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 319.1 (369.2) -> 297.9 (322.1) MB, 166.3 / 0.0 ms  (average 
mu = 0.948, current mu = 0.315) last resort; GC in old space requested
[8936:09216D50]    40082 ms: Mark-sweep (reduce) 297.9 (322.1) -> 297.6 (322.1) MB, 201.0 / 0.0 ms  (average 
mu = 0.873, current mu = 0.001) last resort; GC in old space requested


<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

Im trying to find the problem with the chrome developer console, by opening the expo app in web.
I tried multiple things:

Measure Performance (ticked Memory) while starting the app:
The error `doesnt` occure any more. But as soon as I stop the recording, the app is reloading

```
Web  ./index.js ░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░  0.0% (0/1)
```

and crashing with the same error. When I reload the app/web while the recording is live, everything happen as expected.

Same thing for the Performance insights in the chrome developer console.

The only tool working, is the Memory. There I get this result:
[image: Chrome Developer Tools Memory]

When I remove the Amplify imports from my app (only the imports implemeneted, no functionality at the moment), the app is not crashing and I can even measure the Performance in Chrome developer console. With removing this:

```
import { Amplify } from "aws-amplify";
import awsconfig from '../src/aws-exports';
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
```

I get this performance result and no error:
[image]

How can i solve this problem?
Any help is kindly received.